# Запуск команд командной строки через файл .py

Tags: python-3.x

есть ли способ запускать команды системы Windows (скажем, открыть блокнот) через скрипты Питона?

Comment: `import os os.system('cd ..')`

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть такой способ, как указано выше - с помощью стандартного модуля os. `os.system("команда для выполнения")`. Кроме того, можно воспользоваться непосредственно некоторыми командами не через функцию `system()`: `os.mkdir()`, `os.listdir()` и т.д.

Здесь можно прочитать подробнее: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html